# c# How do I select a list box item when I have the value name in a string?

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a string 'item3' and a listbox with 'item1,item2,item3,item4', how do I select item3 in the list box when I have the item name in a string?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code if selectedValue doesn't work?

Comment: Are you using WPF? I know that the SelectedValue is not R/W in a few controls. If so, remember to tag WPF questions as WPF. If not, ignore me ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
int index = listBox1.FindString("item3");
// Determine if a valid index is returned. Select the item if it is valid.
if (index != -1)
     listBox1.SetSelected(index,true);
```

Comment: Or you can do lb.SelectedIndex = lb.FindStringExact(fieldValue);

Comment: None of these work for me, because I don't have .SetSelected() function... I just discovered that I am using ListBox from System.Controls and that it's different..

Answer (score 4):

```
listBox.FindStringExact("item3");
```

Returns the index of the first item found, or ListBox.NoMatches if no match is found.

you can then call

```
listBox.SetSelected(index, true);
```

to select this item

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`ListBox.SetSelected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.setselected.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
public bool SelectItem(ListBox listBox, string item)
    {
        bool contains = listBox.Items.Contains(item);
        if (!contains)
            return false;
        listBox.SelectedItem = item;
        return listBox.SelectedItems.Contains(item);
    }
```

Test method:

```
public void Test()
    {
        string item = "item1";
        if (!SelectItem(listBox, item))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Item not found.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Better message would be "Item not found."

Answer (score 1):

SelectedValue will work only if you have set the ValueMember for the listbox.

Further, even if you do set the ValueMember, selectedValue will not work if your ListBox.Sorted = true.

Check out my post on [Setting selected item in a ListBox without looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877519/setting-selected-item-in-a-listbox-without-looping/1123398#1123398)

You can try one of these approaches:

1. `lb.SelectedValue = fieldValue;`
2. `lb.SelectedIndex = lb.FindStringExact(fieldValue);`
3. This is a generic method for all listboxes. Your implementation will change based on what you are binding to the list box. In my case it is DataTable.

   ```
   private void SetSelectedIndex(ListBox lb, string value)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < lb.Items.Count; i++)
       {
           DataRowView dr = lb.Items[i] as DataRowView;
           if (dr["colName"].ToString() == value)
           {
               lb.SelectedIndices.Add(i);
               break;
           }
       }    
   }
   ```

Comment: This is the first time I see a girl in SO. Good to see. But anyway my insticts are urging to point out some mistake with no avail. your answer is perfectly correct(so far I checked).

Answer (score 0):

Isn't SelectedValue read/write?

Comment: I've tried lstbox.selectedvalue = strItem; but that didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Is this WinForms or WebForms?

Answer (score 0):

```
static class ControlHelper
{
    public static void SelectExactMatch(this ComboBox c, string find)
    {
        c.SelectedIndex = c.FindStringExact(find, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CheckBoxList.Items.FindByValue("Value").Selected = true;
```